# Selenium routing with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a docker compose file for doing Capybara tests inside a container. 
The problem i'm currently facing to is that i can't find a ability to to route the subdomains of my lvh.me domain. When I add lvh.me to the hosts file of Selenium I get the same result that my tests are failing. In which way can I add some routing for subdomains to Selenium to accept subdomains like **{{user}}.lvh.me:3001**

My Capybara configuration

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara.app_host = "http://0.0.0.0:3001"
  Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
  Capybara.server_port = '3001'
  Capybara.always_include_port = true

  args = ['--no-default-browser-check', '--headless', '--start-maximized']
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => args})

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :remote,
      url: "http://hub:4444/wd/hub",
      desired_capabilities: caps
    )
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_driver = :rack_test
  config.javascript_driver = :selenium
end
```

And my docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
    - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
    - ./tmp/redis:/var/lib/redis/data
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis
    - DATABASE_HOST=db
    command: sh "/myapp/docker-entrypoint.sh"
    volumes:
    - .:/myapp
    links:
    - db
    - redis
    - hub
    depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3000:3000"
  hub:
    container_name: hub
    image: selenium/hub:3.9
    ports:
    - "4444:4444"
  selenium:
    container_name: selenium
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.9
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
    depends_on:
      - hub
    links:
      - hub
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you shouldn't be specifying the Capybara config inside the driver registration. Secondly, this is going to assume you're running your tests on the `web` docker instance -- if you're actually trying to run your tests on the host then things would be slightly different.

`Capybara.app_host` needs to be set to a URL that points to where the app under test is running from the perspective of the browser. In your case the browser is running on the `selenium` docker instance, and the tests should start the AUT on the `web` instance - that would mean `Capybara.app_host` should be `http://web` (port is not needed since you've specified `alway_include_port`).  That means you should end up with

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  args = ['--no-default-browser-check', '--headless', '--start-maximized']
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => args})

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :remote,
    url: "http://hub:4444/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.app_host = "http://web"
  config.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
  config.server_port = '3001'
  config.always_include_port = true

  config.default_driver = :rack_test
  config.javascript_driver = :selenium
end
```

Your next issue it you want to use which `lvh.me` which resolves to `127.0.0.1` but you need it to resolve to whatever ip is assigned to the `web` docker instance. If you have a fixed number of subdomains used in your tests you should be able to handle that via `link` aliases specified in the `selenium` docker instance config - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links - or via network aliases if you specify networks in your docker compose config - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases.  If you do actually need to resolve wildcard (*.lvh.me) then you'll need to run your own DNS server (possibly in your docker setup) with a wildcard CNAME entry that resolves `*.lvh.me` to `web`